# Unable to connect to dockerized redis from outside the local machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to connect to Redis running on docker from the spring boot app on the outside machine/remote machine. I am unable to connect to redis. Doing telnet host_ip port also gives connection timed out. I have changed the bind address to 0.0.0.0 and protected mode to no. I have also checked the port and the port is open. One thing to note - when i am connecting to redis from my workplace network it connects and works fine but not from the home using the workplace vpn which is same network. In same docker my db is also running but it works fine and connects from remote pc also.

Local Configuration-

```
spring.redis.host=some_host_ip
spring.redis.port=6379
```

Here is the docker compose structure-

```
redis:
 image: redis:latest
 ports:
  - "6379:6379"
 command:
  redis-server --port 6379 --bind 0.0.0.0 --appendonly no --save "" --protected-mode no
 networks:
  - redis-net
 volumes:
  - cache_data:/redia_data
```

Checking bind address using redis-cli CONFIG GET bind gives 0.0.0.0 but connection fails.

Comment: it's likely that the issue lies somewhere in the network configuration outside of Docker.